# How to reformat the URL by removing extra slashes

Tags: javascript

This might be simple and stupid question. But, I'm playing with an API and it returned me the following URL structure:

```
"https:\/\/s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com\/xxxxx-uploads\/users\/avatar\/fae764d0abea565f8e8524805a3285579568f7f2.jpg"
```

How can I remove the extra slashed from this string using javascript?

Comment: Are the double quotes part of the string content too, or did you add them just for display in the question?

Comment: Then you can use `JSON.parse()` to create string data without the quotes or backslashes. https://jsfiddle.net/rk42L7yd/1/

Comment: woa! that easy :) Can you post it as the answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it seems that the content you're given is a valid JS or JSON string, you can use `JSON.parse()` or `eval()` to convert it from the serialization to  actual JS string data without the quotes and escape sequences.

We'll use `JSON.parse` for safety since you're getting it from an external source.

```
var s = JSON.parse(url_data);
console.log(s);
```